# Dictionary to JSON for loop

Tags: python, json, string, loops, dictionary

I've tried just about everything to convert a dictionary that looks like this in Python:

```
d = {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 26}
```

I know you're able to access values like this:

```
d['name']
> Jack
```

I would like to do this in a for loop though:

```
for obj in d:
   print(obj['name'])
```

Any ideas how? I've tried both json.loads and json.dumps on obj but keep getting errors like: `string indices must be integers`. How can I can access specific keys and get their values like the example above?

Comment: ....convert a dictionary to what? What exactly is the end goal?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete dataset please? Iteration won't work in this case because `obj` is a key name, therefore a string so passing a string to it will result in the error you are getting.

Comment: I've said it in the post, the end goal is to print keys in the for loop just like how you'd do it outside of one.

Comment: Indeed, you can convert a dictionary to JSON like `json.dumps({'name': 'Jack', 'age': 26})`

Comment: If you want to print the keys, just print `obj` in your loop.

Comment: @flowermia if you just want to print the keys, why not `print(d.keys())`? what am i missing?  Or like Scott says, print `obj` in your loop

Comment: I don't want to print keys, I've provided an example in my post of what I want the output to be like. This is not the dataset I'm working with. @ScottHunter

Comment: @flowermia ok but you just said you wanted to print keys. I'm just trying to understand the goal. You can print keys and key:value pairs in the for loop. Maybe `print(d[obj])` is what you're after?

Comment: @flowermia: is your `d` , in actual dataset, a dictionary or list of dictionaries or dictionary or dictionaries. If it is a list of dictionaries, then your for loop logic would work!

Comment: I never said I want to print the keys, I want to be able to access keys like obj['name'] to print 'Jack' in the for loop.

Comment: @flowermia, in the 3rd comment, you write `"the end goal is to print keys in the for loop"`. Why do you need `obj`? why not just `d['name']`?

Comment: Ok, sorry that was a mistake. I need obj because my dictionary has multiple values, e.g. {'person-1': {'name':'Jack', 'age':'26'}, 'person-2': {'name':'Idk', 'age':'23'}}. I need to iterate and JUST get the names of each person using a for loop.

Comment: @flowermia Ahh ok, so this isn't working because your test dictionary doesn't have the same structure as your actual data, and then change to `d[obj]['name']` in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `.values()` of your main dict

```
d = {'person-1': {'name':'Jack', 'age':'26'}, 'person-2': {'name':'Idk', 'age':'23'}}

for obj in d.values():
    print(obj['name'])

Jack
Idk
```

---

And `.items()` to get the outer key with

```
for key, obj in d.items():
    print(key, obj['name'])

person-1 Jack
person-2 Idk
```

Comment: yea or that i suppose

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was after!

Comment: @flowermia you can think about accepting the answer so ;) green tick on left ot it